# Robotframework - access regular expression matching groups

Tags: robotframework

How can I access matching groups in regular expressions?

For example:   ${line} =   Set variable  String with-8

How could I grab the 'String with' part and the number part in seperate variables?

I tried:

```
Test case determining strings and number
    ${line} =   Set variable  String with-8
    ${resultRegexp} =  Evaluate  re.search('(.+)\\-(\\d+)', '''${line}''')
    Log  The string(s) part is: ${resultRegexp[0]   # or group(1) or so
    Log  The number part is: ${resultRegexp[1]   # or group(2) or so
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem on your test is the missing import of module `re` in the `Evaluate` keyword. I also corrected the input string, and this is your working test:

```
Test case determining strings and number
    ${line} =    Set variable    String with-8
    ${resultRegexp}=    Evaluate    re.search("(.*)\\-(\\d+)", "${line}"), re
    Log    The string(s) part is: ${resultRegexp[0].group(1)}    # or group(1) or so
    Log    The number part is: ${resultRegexp[0].group(2)}    # or group(2) or so
```

This is the output it produces with RIDE:

```
Starting test: Test Regular Exp.Test case determining strings and number
20201004 18:16:32.817 :  INFO : ${line} = String with-8
20201004 18:16:32.819 :  INFO : ${resultRegexp} = (<re.Match object; span=(0, 13), match='String with-8'>, <module 're' from '/usr/lib64/python3.8/re.py'>)
20201004 18:16:32.821 :  INFO : The string(s) part is: String with
20201004 18:16:32.822 :  INFO : The number part is: 8
Ending test: Test Regular Exp.Test case determining strings and number
```

But Robot Framework includes some keywords for Regular Expressions in the String library. See below a full working example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           String

*** Test Cases ***
Test case determining strings and number
    ${line} =    Set variable    String with-8
    ${resultRegexp}=    String.Get Regexp Matches    ${line}    (.*)\\-(\\d+)    1    2
    Log    The string(s) part is: ${resultRegexp[0][0]}    # First element of tuple
    Log    The number part is: ${resultRegexp[0][1]}    # Second element of tuple
```

This is the output it produces with RIDE:

```
Starting test: Test Regular Exp.Test case determining strings and number
20201004 18:28:36.606 :  INFO : ${line} = String with-8
20201004 18:28:36.609 :  INFO : ${resultRegexp} = [('String with', '8')]
20201004 18:28:36.611 :  INFO : The string(s) part is: String with
20201004 18:28:36.612 :  INFO : The number part is: 8
Ending test: Test Regular Exp.Test case determining strings and number
```